# Currency Locale- How to get the locale for the different countries

Tags: java, javascript, currency, currency-formatting

```
public  double showinbrl(double amount, double rate) {
        double amountinbrl = amount * rate; 
        NumberFormat brl = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.BRAZIL); 
        brl.format(amountinbrl);
        return amountinbrl;
    }
```

how to get the locale for the different countries... i cant find locale for brazil..

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NumberFormat brl = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("pt_BR"));
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATING 2023 (KOTLIN):

When I tried to use "Locale.forLanguageTag("pt_BR")" it didn't work for me, it's not formatting correctly and it's showing an unknown character:

[image: unknown character appearing when using Locale.forLanguageTag("pt_BR")]

So I googled and used the following code and it worked:

```
val brl = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("pt", "BR"))
```

[image: Brazil currency character displayed correctly by using Locale("pt", "BR")]